# Problem saving/updating files in TeXshop

Tags: errors, texshop

I have been using the same version of TeXshop (2.47) since it was first released. Today I encountered a new problem. I cannot save from TeXshop to a folder. I get a message:

```
"The document “Untitled” could not be saved as “Untitled”."
```

regardless of what directory I ask it to be saved in. I also cannot update files -- same message. I am able to save to the desired directories from other applications, so it isn't a general saving problem. Any ideas? (I don't want to reinstall TeXshop because I have a version with <kbd>"Save as"</kbd>, which I really like, and in later versions that got replaced with <kbd>"Duplicate"</kbd> which requires a lot more on the user's part.)

Comment: what version of Mac OS are you running?

Comment: Welcome! 2.47 is really very old. More importantly, if you are running a recent version of OS X, then it just isn't designed to work with it. According to the [home page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html), 2.47 should work for OS X versions 10.4 through 10.6. That is, Tiger, Leopard or Snow Leopard, if I remember correctly. Anything later than that requires a later version of the editor. 3.65 for Lion. 3.73 for Mountain Lion or later. Hopefully you are not running an (insecure) OS suitable for 2.47!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice and the welcome! I haven't upgraded to Yosemite, because I use an older MacBook Pro and my experience with the combination Yosemite + older MacBook Pro is that the machine runs excruciatingly slowly.

So I gave in and updated, and lost my beloved "save as" option. And had the same problem. This time I had the wisdom to check if other files would save, and they did. So it was a problem with the file, not with TexShop generally.

Turns out, I had copied (from a PDF) a passage that had several non-qwerty symbols in it and hadn't changed all the symbols to qwerty symbols. Once I did that, it saved normally. I was surprised -- my usual experience is that TexShop simply doesn't print those symbols. So I'm not sure exactly what the non-save trigger was.

Comment: The Save As option still exists, it's just a bit hidden. If you hold down the Option key in the File menu, Save As will reappear. Its key combination is Command-Option-Shift-S.

Comment: Alan Munn, THANK YOU! I can do this! I'd never heard of using the Option key that way, so you have not only returned "Save As" to my life, but you have opened a whole new world of possibilities!!

Comment: You can also bring back `Save as` permanently by assigning a shortcut: • Open System Preferences and choose "Keyboards"
• Click the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab and choose "Application Shortcuts" from the list on the left
• Press the [+] plus button to add a new shortcut, and for Menu Title type "Save As..." exactly, with the periods
• Click to "Keyboard Shortcut" and hit the familiar Command+Shift+S, then click "Add"

Comment: It would be really interesting how many working hours were globally lost because people were searching for the `Save as` menu after the mac update.

Comment: Samcarter, is there a way to change or add to the subject-categories for this post? Your and Alan's information about "save as" is extremely useful, but kind of buried here.

Comment: Ok now what?! Save as... Has disappeared from the menu when I click Option, AND while other apps accept the configured Shift-Command-S as "save as...", TexShop 3.62 does nothing. Grrrr!